# Extend admin login session lifetime Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, session

As my admin account will be logged out for every 1 hour, I am wondering if there is any way that I can do to change my the session lifetime for all my admin accounts.

Here are what I have done:

> Magento backend > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security >
>   Session lifetime(seconds): 86400
>
> Magento backend > General > Web > Session Cookie Management > Cookie
>   Lifetime; 86400

Change in phpMyadmin: 
[image]

However, it is still not working. Is there any more things I have to change in order to extend my admin session lifetime?

Comment: Check your code files, and make sure the value is not hard coded any where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your php.ini file, and check for the value `session.gc_maxlifetime`
Set some higher value which you want. Restart your server and check.

Comment: How to find this file (php.ini)? As I went to my Magento root, there isn't any file have this name. After I research, there is solution that ask me to create a file call 'phpinfo.php' and key in  <?php phpinfo(); ?> in this file. How should I proceed after this? Btw, really thank you for the reply!

Comment: php.ini file is your server's php configuration file. Please check your server's php folder.

Comment: If you are on shared hosting you probably won't have access to the php.ini. It is possible your hosts will not change the lifetime value either because it may impact other hosted sites.